# JdbcTemplate queryForObject() with error when using with parameters

Tags: java, spring

I got the error org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException
with detailMessage "Incorrect result size: excepted 1, actual 0"

When executed:

```
Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT ID FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_PROP = ?", new Object[]{"00"}, Long.class);
```

But it works when I have executed:

```
Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT ID FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_PROP = '00'", Long.class);
```

Describe columns (Oracle DB):

ID - NUMBER(4)

SOME_PROP - CHAR(4)

This is a fictional example to demonstrate the problem. What is the error, please explain!!

Comment: Why are you passing an array as parameter (i.e. `new Object[]{"00"}`)? Is it your expectation to look for any of the items in the array? Like a `SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN(?)`?

Comment: Yes, it helped! "cast(? as char(n))"
The problem was found only with the char type(n)!
For varchar(n), varchar2 (n) everything is ok and without casting.

I think this is a Oracle JDBC driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it as an object. Try storing as a String and pass as input. I think it should work fine.

EmptyResultDataException occurs only when you don't have a value for that query.
Since you are using queryforObject it expects a value from the given query. Else it throws EmpltyResultDataException.

Comment: `Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT ID FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_PROP = ?", new String[]{"00"}, Long.class);` 
If that's what you're talking about, it doesn't work. And typing is a bad tone, I can pass different parameters